# dataTables search messed up by input from another form

Tags: javascript, datatables

hello i have a form like this

```
<form id="ricerca" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action=""><table class="inserisci_modifica">
<tr class="visualizza_dati">

<td class="nome_campo"><label for="ragsoc_denominazione">Ragione sociale o denominazione</label></td>
<td class="valore_campo">
<input type="text" name="ragsoc_denominazione" id="ragsoc_denominazione" value="" tabindex="1" /></td>
<td class="nome_campo"><label for="piva">Partita IVA</label></td>
<td class="valore_campo">
<input type="text" name="piva" id="piva" value="" tabindex="9" /></td></tr>
```

then i have an html table to which i apply dataTables

and then i have this code

```
$("#ricerca").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnClearTable();//Empty the entire table of current row information.
    oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

the problem is when i type something in my form, it's as if it gets auto submited as dataTables's search field, and then i can see the same text in dataTables search field, i can't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind i find the bug, i am using a plugin, and in dataTableExt.oApi.fnSetFilteringDelay
i had to change

```
anControl = $( 'input', _that.fnSettings().aanFeatures.f );
```

to

```
anControl = $( 'table.dataTables input', _that.fnSettings().aanFeatures.f );
```